# Auction Algorithm Optimization in C++

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

I have written the following [Auction Algorithm](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/3233/P-2064-24690022.pdf?sequence=1) implementation in C++ and I am having issues with performance. On my machine a problem size of 500 is solved in about 7 seconds while a similar Matlab version solves the same in about 4-5 seconds. Since C++ should run faster, what are some ways that I can squeeze some more performance out of this code? Are there any blatant pitfalls or bottlenecks which I can avoid?

Note that I am not looking for algorithmic improvements, I am mostly looking for feedback into what is fast C++ and what is not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define INF numeric_limits<int>::max()
#define VERBOSE false

/* Pre-declare functions to allow arbitry call ordering  */
void auction(int N);
void auctionRound(vector<int>* assignment, vector<double>* prices, vector<int> C, double epsilon);
vector<int> makeRandC(int size);
void printMatrix(vector<int> mat, int size);
vector<double> findUnAssig(vector<double>* v);
void vecMax(vector<auto> v, auto* maxVal, int* maxInd);
vector<int> getIndicesWithVal(vector<int> v, int val);
bool hasValue(vector<int> v, int val);
void printVec(vector<auto> v);
vector<double> getVecSubset(vector<double> v, vector<int> subIndices);
void reset(vector<auto>* v, auto val);
void valueMaxSecMax(vector<auto> v1, vector<auto> v2, auto* maxVal, int* maxInd, auto* secMaxVal, int* secMaxInd);
void vecMaxFromSubset(vector<auto> v, vector<int> indices, auto* maxVal, int* maxInd);

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a problem size: ";
    int probSize;
    cin >> probSize;
    auction(probSize);
    return 0;
}

void auction(int N)
{
    vector<int> C = makeRandC(N);

    if (VERBOSE)
    {
        cout << "Cost matrix: " << endl;
        printMatrix(C, N);
    }

    /* Begin Time */
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    clock_t start = clock();


    vector<int> assignment(N, INF);
    vector<double> prices(N, 1);
    double epsilon = 1.0;
    int iter = 1;

    while(epsilon > 1.0/N)
    {
        reset(&assignment, INF);
        while (find(assignment.begin(), assignment.end(), INF) != assignment.end())
        {
            iter++;
            auctionRound(&assignment, &prices, C, epsilon);

        }
        epsilon = epsilon * .25;
    }


    clock_t end = clock();


    /* End Time */
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double timing = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    double time = (double) (end-start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;

    cout << "Num Iterations:\t" << iter << endl;
    cout << "Total time:\t" << timing / 1000.0 << endl;
    cout << "Total CPU time:\t" << time << endl;

    if (VERBOSE)
    {
        cout << endl << endl << "Solution: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < assignment.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "Person " << i << " gets object " << assignment[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}

void auctionRound(vector<int>* assignment, vector<double>* prices, vector<int> C, double epsilon)
{

    /* Prints the assignment and price vectors */
    if (VERBOSE)
    {
        cout << endl << "Assignment: \t\t";
        printVec(*assignment);
        cout << "prices: \t\t";
        printVec(*prices);
        cout << endl;
    }

    int N = prices->size();

    /* 
        These are meant to be kept in correspondance such that bidded[i]  
        and bids[i] correspond to person i bidding for bidded[i] with bid bids[i]
    */
    vector<int> tmpBidded;
    vector<double> tmpBids;
    vector<int> unAssig;

    /* Compute the bids of each unassigned individual and store them in temp */
    for (int i = 0; i< assignment->size(); i++)
    {
        if (assignment->at(i) == INF)
        {
            unAssig.push_back(i);
            /* Finds the row of our cost matrix corresponding to the ith unassigned person */
            // vector<int> rowInt = getRow(C, i);
            vector<double> row(C.begin() + i*N, C.begin() + (i+1)*N);

            /* 
                Need the best and second best value of each object to this person
                where value is calculated row_{j} - prices{j}
            */
            double optValForI, secOptValForI;
            int optObjForI, secOptObjForI;
            valueMaxSecMax(row, *prices, &optValForI, &optObjForI, &secOptValForI, &secOptObjForI);

            /* Computes the highest reasonable bid for the best object for this person */
            double bidForI = optValForI - secOptValForI + epsilon;

            /* Stores the bidding info for future use */
            tmpBidded.push_back(optObjForI);
            tmpBids.push_back(bidForI);
        }
    }

    /* 
        Each object which has received a bid determines the highest bidder and 
        updates its price accordingly
    */
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        vector<int> indices = getIndicesWithVal(tmpBidded, j);
        if (indices.size() != 0)
        {
            double highestBidForJ;
            int i_j;

            vecMaxFromSubset(tmpBids, indices, &highestBidForJ, &i_j);

            for (int i = 0; i < assignment->size(); i++)
            {
                if (assignment->at(i) == j)
                {
                    if (VERBOSE)
                        cout << "Person " << unAssig[i_j] << " was assigned object " << i << " but it will now be unassigned" << endl;
                    assignment->at(i) = INF;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (VERBOSE)
                cout << "Assigning object " << j << " to person " << unAssig[i_j]<< endl;
            assignment->at(unAssig[i_j]) = j;
            prices->at(j) = prices->at(j) + highestBidForJ;
        }
    }
}


/*<--------------------------------------   Utility Functions   -------------------------------------->*/

vector<int> makeRandC(int size)
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    vector<int> mat(size * size, 2);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            mat[i + j * size] = rand() % size + 1;
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

void printMatrix(vector<int> mat, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cout << mat[i + j * size] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void printVec(vector<auto> v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v[i] == INF)
        {
            cout << "INF" << "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << v[i] << "\t";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void vecMax(vector<auto> v, auto* maxVal, int* maxInd)
{
    *maxVal = -INF;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v[i] > *maxVal)
        {
            *maxVal = v[i];
            *maxInd = i;
        }
    }
}

void vecMaxFromSubset(vector<auto> v, vector<int> indices, auto* maxVal, int* maxInd)
{
    *maxVal = -INF;
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i++)
    {
        auto curVal = v[indices[i]];
        if (v[i] > *maxVal)
        {
            *maxVal = curVal;
            *maxInd = indices[i];
        }
    }
}

/* Finds the top two values and indices from the value vector v1 - v2 */
void valueMaxSecMax(vector<auto> v1, vector<auto> v2, auto* maxVal, int* maxInd, auto* secMaxVal, int* secMaxInd)
{
    *maxVal = -INF;
    *secMaxVal = -INF;
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
    {
        auto curVal = v1[i] - v2[i];
        if (curVal > *maxVal)
        {
            *secMaxVal = *maxVal;
            *secMaxInd = *maxInd;
            *maxVal = curVal;
            *maxInd = i;
        }
        else if (curVal > *secMaxVal)
        {
            *secMaxVal = curVal;
            *secMaxInd = i;
        }
    }
}

/* Returns a vector of indices from v which have the specified value val */
vector<int> getIndicesWithVal(vector<int> v, int val)
{
    vector<int> out;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v[i] == val)
        {
            out.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return out;
}

bool hasValue(vector<int> v, int val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v[i] == val)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void reset(vector<auto>* v, auto val)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v->size(); i++)
    {
        v->at(i) = val;
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
For anyone interested, I implemented JS1's advice and I can now solve the size 500 problem in ~.2 seconds. The updated code can be found [here](https://github.com/EvanOman/AuctionAlgorithm/blob/master/auction.cpp).

EDIT 2: 
In light of nwp's comment, I compiled the copy-less version of my code with the optimization flag `-O3` and I can now solve the size 500 problem in ~.02 seconds.

Comment: Did you turn on optimizations in your compiler? Chances are unnecessary copies are optimized out without jumping through reference loops and then some.

Comment: I had never thought to use the compiler optimizations. Compiling the original code with the flag `-O3`  reduced the size 500 run-time to ~1 second. I am not sure how it achieved this improvement, though it seems to have not removed all vector copying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copying vectors

I ran your program and it was indeed quite slow.  After debugging your program for a bit, I realized that you are copying vectors all over the place even though you probably don't mean to.  The biggest offender is here, because the vector `C` is of size \$N^2\$:

```
void auctionRound(vector<int>* assignment, vector<double>* prices,
                  vector<int> C, double epsilon);
```

When I changed this function to use a reference instead:

```
void auctionRound(vector<int>* assignment, vector<double>* prices,
                  vector<int> &C, double epsilon);
```

Then your program ran about 7x faster on a 1000 size input.

When I removed **all** of your vector copies from your functions, including the temporary `row` vector you create, then I got your program to run around 50x faster on a 1000 size input.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much for the response, that was precisely the issue! Just out of curiosity what tools/methods did you use when you where debugging?

Comment: @evan058 I'd imagine just reading the code. It is a very common mistake among beginner C++ developers and is quite obvious to most C++ developers with more than a few months of experience.

Comment: @evan058 For this program I didn't use an actual debugger, but I did run your code on various sized inputs to get a sense of the speed of it.  Then I looked at your program to find out what could possibly be so slow.  At first I thought it was the `row` vector that you made a copy of, but after "fixing" it to pass in `C` instead, I made it worse instead of better because it was now copying the whole `C` instead of just one row.  That's when I realized your vectors were being copied instead of being passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

In methods, pass collections by reference except if you *need* a copy (ie: for local modification).

ie:

```
void valueMaxSecMax(vector<auto> v1, vector<auto> v2 ...
```

should be:

```
void valueMaxSecMax(vector<auto>& v1, vector<auto>& v2 ...
```

If you don't want a copy of v1 and v2 each time it's called.
(This applies to printMatrix, printVec, vecMax, ...)

This alone should reduce the time by an order of magnitude.